# What does /to/ mean in your convert iso to img for mac

Tags: 12.04

What does /to/ mean in convert .iso to .img in your tut for mac osx and can i install ubuntu on mac osx 10.5.8

link to /to/
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `~/path/to/` with the path of the folder where you saved the ISO image, for example `~/Downloads/`:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/Downloads/target.img ~/Downloads/ubuntu.iso
```